# Enforce limit on numeric input.

Tags: php, html, css

So I have this:

```
<input name="data[Donation][amount]" value="0.00" step="any" maxlength="12" type="number" id="DonationAmount">
```

My question is how to I make absolutely sure that no negative numbers are put into this field?  If possible I would like to secure it on both the back and front ends.

Thanks.

Comment: You will never trust client side.

Comment: Validate in server side also...

Comment: What have you tried? What does qualify as a negative number in your case? What does qualify as a non-negative number in your question?

Answer (score 1):

On Client side you can test with JavaScript like

```
var num=123.45;
$("#DonationAmount").val().match(/^[0-9.]+$/)
```

And on server side you can check like

```
$num = "100";
if ( (int)$num == $num && (int)$num > 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use min and max attributes for that!

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" />
```

Allows user to select number between 0 and 10!

And if your backend is built with PHP, you can check it out like this:

```
if($_POST["data"]["Donation"]["amount"] < 0) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Front end you should javascript to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checknumber(val)
{
    if(val < 0)
    {
         alert('invalid value');
    }
}
</script>

<input name="data[Donation][amount]" value="0.00" step="any" maxlength="12" type="number" id="DonationAmount" onblur="checknumber(this.value)">
```

while on server side you can do this...

```
<?php
    $Amount = $_POST["data"]["Donation"]["amount"];

    if($Amount < 0 || !is_numeric($Amount))
    {
        echo "Invalid value";
    }
?>
```

Comment: $_POST['buy']=6-10; change it like this and try, removed the qoutes else it will take it as string. :)

Comment: @TheOptometrist how one can insert 6-10 while the input type is "number"

Comment: never trust the client mohit! @PrasanthBendra exactly

Comment: @TheOptometrist I think you're right, I've changed the code...

Answer (score 0):

Client Side:

```
$("#DonationAmount").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 45 || event.which == 189 ) {
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

This will make sure '-'sign cant enter in text field

Server side :

```
if($_POST["data"]["Donation"]["amount"] < 0) {
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input name="data[Donation][amount]" value="0.00" step="any" maxlength="12" min="0" type="number" id="DonationAmount">
```